# Firebase push notification opens count not working

Tags: android, ios, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase cloud messaging "Push notifications" properly in android and iOS

I can receive the notifications in my devices both iOS and android but I'm not able to see the count of opened notification in Firebase console!

Is there a thing to enable this in code or Firebase console?

Thanks for the help in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did you find a solution to this, @cs4alhaider? I can see open rates etc. for Android but not iOS. Thanks

Comment: Did you find a solution? For me, it was working fine until the 25th of July when we suddenly started getting 0% opens for all the push messages (when we normally used to have around 10-20%). We didn't do any app release around that date either...

Comment: Any Solutions ?

Comment: We have the same problem, after years. Did you find any questions about this problem? Currently, we tried all ways for solving the problem. But we couldn't find any solution for it. Unfortunately, I think this is a Firebase-based problem.